# A Strategy for using PDO? (Pushing results into an Array)

Tags: php, pdo

Here is my somewhat broken strategy

- If it is a query with no input ( always the same ), just use query();

  ```
  $results = $this->database_top->query( $query );
  ```
- If a single row is returned and there is input, do the prep (not shown here) and use

  ```
  $results = $pdoStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  ```
- If multiple rows are returned and there is input,do the prep (not shown here) and use:

  ```
  $results = $pdoStatement->fetchAll();
  ```

Problem I'm facing is that I need the first method to return an array or array of arrays like the second and third.

Prep looks like this FYI

```
$this->database_top->quote($query);  // quote it
$pdoStatement = $this->database_top->prepare($query);  // prepare it
$results = $pdoStatement->execute($parameterArray); // execute it
```

How can I modify my code so that all 3 methods return arrays or array of arrays?

**Iterating over query()**

```
$result_array = $this->DatabaseObject->_pdoQuery( 'multiple', 'tweet_model' );
foreach( $result_array as $array_1d )
{
    $array_2d[]=$array_1d; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`query` does not return results, so I'm not sure what you meant on the first example.  `query` returns a PDOStatement.  It's basically the same as:

```
$qry = $db->query("...");
//equiv:
$qry = $db->prepare("...");
$qry->execute();
```

As vicTROLLA noted, the simplest solution is to just use:

```
$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

However, if you need to process the results as you go for some reason, you could always loop over them manually.

```
$stmt = ...;
$results = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $results[] = $row;
}
//use or return $results
```

`$results` will thus always be an array with 0 or more arrays inside of it.

I find it useful to build arrays where the array key is the primary key of the record:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $results[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

Also, I suspect that you've misunderstood the purpose and functionality of [quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).  It is used for escaping strings that you are going to interpolate into a query, not for magically escaping all values in a query (hence `$db->quote($query)` makes no sense).

Even worse is that drivers are not required to support quote.  (Though it does at least return false if there's no support.)

`prepare` is *massively* preferred over `quote`.

Comment: The reason I'm upvoting is because this is an indirectly good answer. ->fetchAll() (especially PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) will burn a ton of memory on large result sets. Iterating over this in a while loop will yield better performance. Whether or not I agree with iterating over the result set and pushing it into an associative array ($result) anyways is out of scope for this comment.

Comment: @vicTROLLA I actually considered fetchAll, and started to write to use it.  But then I remembered that the question asker listed that as one of his currently options.  So, either he does not know that you can use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, or he needs to process the data sometimes.  Edit: for the sake of completeness, added a note about fetchAll in the answer.

Comment: I am able to iterate over query() results as updated in my answer.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Right?  PDOStatement is usable in a foreach, so you can do that. I'm not quite sure what you're actually asking?  Your end goal is to build an array of result-arrays, right?  You can do that in any of the half-dozen options presented.  What is the problem with all them?

Comment: @Corbin I think you're still missing the point. ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) degrades the usefulness of the DB's cursor. Maybe I'm paranoid from working with larger datasets that will cripple your web servers. It's always better to iterate over the result object then to simply malloc it into memory.

Comment: I was just saying...I don't know how I want to do it...all I know is this incongruity broke my code..and when I manually made the array...this broke my JSON.parse on the client side.

Comment: fetchAll seems less efficient per vic but as it has worked in another case I'm going to use it for now...later I'll go through and optimize.

Comment: @Vic...what is your suggestion....that I can reference later when I get to that point?

Comment: @vicTROLLA If you're wanting to separate DB content from DB-handling, sometimes dumping it all into an array makes sense (though often in simple situations foreach'ing over a PDOStatement that the code doesn't know is a PDOStatement would work).  In that situation, whether you use fetchAll, or fetch, it's going to be negligible.  But yes, if you're just going to iterate, you might as well just iterate and not bother with the intermediate array.

Comment: Well anyways lots of good pointers in here I can update after I fix my current issue..Thanks a bunch yall.

Comment: @vicTROLLA, often in php, database extensions buffer result sets into php memory as the default config anyway, although you can always deviate from that when needed.

Answer (score 1):

In *all* of those cases, you can do

```
$arrayOfAssocArrays = $pdoStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: At the moment I am not concerned about performance( note below )...are you sure...this works whether I return one row or multiple?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist It always returns an array.  (Meaning: yes)

Comment: It doesn't actually...print_r does not work on it...it's returning an array of objects or similar.